# How to call a DSP function with OpaquePointer?

Tags: swift, swift3, accelerate-framework

From Vector-Scalar Linear Algebra Functions (from vectorOps.h)
https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/1546030-visamax

> func vIsamax(_ count: Int32, 
>              _ x: OpaquePointer) -> Int32)

count
Number of elements in the vector x; must be a multiple of 4.

x A vector array of float values.

i've tried solutions from 
https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html
`UnsafeRawPointer`, `withUnsafePointer`, `MemoryLayout`, etc
as of yet no success

cannot invoke initializer for type 'OpaquePointer' with ... CFData,

cannot invoke "        "          with... yada, yada, yada

How to call a DSP function with OpaquePointer?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: i went through 15 different variations from the migration page

Comment: Note that you really shouldn't use `vIsamax`, which exists only for legacy support. You should use either `cblas_isamax` or `vDSP_maxmgvi` instead (these are faster and also available on new platforms like iOS, but `vIsamax` is OS X only -- they also have more accurate documentation, since they're actively developed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`vIsamax`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/1546030-visamax) takes a vector of `vFloat` aka `float4` elements as argument.
(Each `float4` holds 4 floating point numbers.)
The C declaration is

```
int32_t vIsamax(int32_t count, const vFloat *x);
```

which *should* be mapped to Swift as

```
public func vIsamax(_ count: Int32, _ x: UnsafePointer<vFloat>) -> Int32
```

instead of

```
public func vIsamax(_ count: Int32, _ x: OpaquePointer) -> Int32
```

But you can simply pass an `vFloat`/`float4` array, as shown in this
small example:

```
import Swift
import Accelerate
import simd

let values = [ float4(-1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -4.0), float4(4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0) ]
let idx = vIsamax(Int32(4 * values.count), values)
print(idx) // 3
```